# Exponential Distribution as a density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-function

I have an important presentation on tuesday about the exponential distribuion as a density function. My question is: What are the advantages of using this function?

In order to fulfill my task i have to show that this function is "right" and that i can calculate the probability of a certain event. So i have this task:
A bubble pops "in the next second" with the probability of 2%. Calculate the probability for
a.) the bubble pops after one second
b.) the bubble pops after ten seconds.

I already have the answers to this task. But my problem is, that i thought, that the exponential distribution and the corresponding density function would be so helpful, because i can get the probability for longer time intervals. But i was able to find the correct answers to my task above without using the density function. Then i calculated the probability again with the density function and i have the same solution.

So what are the advantages then?

It would be great, if anyone would have an answer to my question.
Oh, and sorry for my English :)
Emily

Comment: How did you find the answer without using the exponential distribution?

Comment: I used a tree diagramm. That´s how i knew that the propability for the bubble to live longer than one minute has to be 98%, when the probability for the bubble to pop the next second is 2%.

Comment: How do you compute the probability that the bubble survives more than $3.23524$ seconds ?

Comment: Yes, I get that, but why do i have the same results then?

Comment: I made a mistake, the questions are:

Comment: a.) what is the probability for the bubble to live longer than 1 sec and b.) longer than 10 sec... sorry

Answer (score 0):

An obvious advantage of using the answer:
$$P_{popped}(t)=1-0.98^t$$
Is that you can plug in an arbitrary value for $t$. It doesn't have to be a whole number. You can then do $1-P_{popped}(t)$ to find $P_{survived}(t)$:
$$P_{survived}(t)=0.98^t$$
It's also a bit easier I suppose to envision the trend of $P(t)$ when using this function rather than looking at discrete probabilities:

[image: plot of p(t)]

I'm not sure why the dots aren't lined up perfectly with the line here, but you get the point.

Comment: but I didn´t use the function you used. I used the density function with lambda and e, and for computing with "normal skills" i used a tree diagramm. Still both results are the same but i would have thought that the one with the density function would have been maybe more exact or another result.

Comment: oh yes, now the second one without the 1- is what i used. and again- i also used the density function.

Comment: $0.98^t = e^{ln(0.98)\cdot t}$. You said yourself that the 'normal method' and the exponential function gave the same result.

Comment: yes they did. but i expected them not to. Otherwise i don't see the advantage of using this density function when i can also use the "normal method".

Comment: Suppose you wanted to calculate the probability at $100\pi$ seconds. How would you do this?

Comment: I would take the density function (the one with lambda and e...) and use the integral of the interval from 0 to 100. and then i would take 1-the result.

Comment: Would you say the density function had an advantage over the normal method in this situation?

Comment: No, because i could also take 100 for t in the function you postet above. I suppose that would be the same result then.

Comment: $100\neq100\pi$

Comment: I´m sorry, i don´t get that. Maybe I am totally wrong with my thinking, i don´t know, maybe i ask the wrong questions.

Comment: I think you misread my previous comment. I said "...calculate the probability at $100\pi$ seconds".

Comment: ooo, sorry. But why not 100?